# Problems again with an isomorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ an isomorphism. Prove that there exist a transformation $g:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $f\circ g$ is the identity in $Y$.

I can't start the proof becasue I haven't got a clear idea what is an isomorphism in  this context. (which is my question)

Comment: Since $X,Y$ has no algebraic structure, isomorphism has no sense here. The function $f$ is simply a bijection. Therefore, your proposition is in fact a "definition".

Answer (score 0):

In a category we talk about the objects of the category and morphisms,
monomorphisms, epimorphisms, and isomorphisms between two objets in
this category.

In your case, the category is a category of sets because you talk about
objects $X$, and $Y$ as set objects (without additional structure).  In this, case morphisms are exactly the maps, monomorphisms are injective functions, epimorphisms are surjective functions, and isomorphisms are bijections.

The existence of the map $g$ such $g\circ f=id_X$
and $f\circ g=id_Y$ is given by the definition of $f$ as an isomorphism, which implies that $f$ is bijective (as indicated in the comment).

Comment: This is impressive, this was the first question of my exam, i can't believe it was that easy ...